# calculate the probability that more than three claims will be received during a consecutive two-month period, given that...

Tags: probability

[image]

### Attempt

Let $N_1$ and $N_2$ be the number of claims received in months 1 and 2. We want to calculate $P(N_1+N_2>3 | N_1 < 2 )$.

First, we calculate $P(N_1 + N_2 > 3 \cap N_1 < 2 )$

Now, clearly $N_1$ can be only $1$ 0r $0$, thus can write

$$ P(N_1 + N_2 > 3 \cap N_1 < 2 ) = P(N_2 > 2 \cup N_2 > 1 ) = P(N_2>2) + P(N_2>1) = 2 - P(N_2 \leq 2)-P(N_2\leq1) = 2 - P(N_2= 2)-2P(N_2=1)-2P(N_2=0) $$

We thus obtain that

$$ P(N_1 + N_2 > 3 \cap N_1 < 2 ) = 2 - \frac{2}{3^3} - \frac{4}{3^2} - \frac{4}{3} $$

Now, we calculate $P(N_1<2)$ this is just

$$ P(N_1=0) + P(N_1=1) = \frac{2}{3} + \frac{2}{3^2} = \frac{24}{3^3} $$

Hence,

$$P(N_1+N_2>3 | N_1 < 2 ) = \frac{ 2 - \frac{2}{3^3} - \frac{4}{3^2} - \frac{4}{3} }{  \frac{24}{3^3} } = \frac{1}{6}$$

now, the answer keys gives $\boxed{ans: 1/54}$. what am I doing wrong in this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition of conditional probability, we have
$$
\mathbb P(N_1+N_2>3\mid N_1<2) = \frac{\mathbb P(N_1+N_2>3,N_1<2)}{\mathbb P(N_1<2)}. $$
Now, 
$$
\mathbb P(N_1<2) = \mathbb P(N_1=0)+\mathbb P(N_1=1) = \frac23+\frac29 = \frac89, 
$$
and
\begin{align}
P(N_1+N_2>3,N_1<2) &= \mathbb P(N_1+N_2> 3,N_1=0)+\mathbb P(N_1+N_2> 3,N_1=1)\\
&= \mathbb P(N_2>3)\mathbb P(N_1=0) + \mathbb P(N_2> 2)\mathbb P(N_1=1)\\
&= (1 - (\mathbb P(N_2=0) + \mathbb P(N_2 =1)+\mathbb P(N_2=2)+\mathbb P(N_2=3))\mathbb P(N_1=0) + (1 - (\mathbb P(N_2=0) + \mathbb P(N_2 =1)+\mathbb P(N_2=2))\mathbb P(N_1=1)\\
&= \left(1 - \left(\frac23+\frac29+\frac2{27}+\frac2{81} \right)\right)\cdot \frac23 + \left(1 - \left(\frac23+\frac29+\frac2{27} \right)\right)\cdot \frac29\\
&= \frac4{81},
\end{align}
so that
$$
\mathbb P(N_1+N_2>3\mid N_1<2) = \frac4{81}\cdot\frac98 = \frac1{54}.
$$